# what could be the reasons for getting "Unable to connect: Request to Snowflake failed" this error

Tags: node.js, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```js
var connection = snowflake.createConnection({
  account: "CX28429.ap-south-1.aws",
  username: "MNK",
  password: "MYPASSWORD",
  warehouse: "COMPUTE_WH",
});

connection.connect((err, conn) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error("Unable to connect: " + err.message);
  } else {
    console.log("Successfully connected to Snowflake, ID:", conn.getId());
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you try `console.error("Unable to connect", err)` instead. There might be more information in the error that you're not seeing

Comment: Also recommend you redact your account and other connection string info (if any of it is correct) in the post above.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you using Snowflake nodejs connector.

1. Did you check if the URL is reachable, put it in the browser and see if you getting a login page or not.

Example:
https://CX28429.ap-south-1.aws.snowflakecomputing.com

If not, you need to whitelist all the Snowflake endpoints and ports against any firewall/proxy etc of the client machine.

You can check it via Snowcd tool
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowcd.html

2. The URL format you using is deprecated, the new URL format is global regionless, its mentioned in the document as well

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/nodejs-driver-use.html#setting-the-connection-options

var connection = snowflake.createConnection({
account: "myaccount.us-east-2",
username: "myusername",
password: "mypassword"
});

The preferred URL format is global regionless format
https://organization_name-account_name.snowflakecomputing.com

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/admin-account-identifier.html#format-1-preferred-account-name-in-your-organization

So please check if Snowcd is passing all the tests or not. Please try and let us know.

There should not be any error from Snowflake nodejs connector unless there is some issue which is blocking the connection.

Regards,
Sujan